# netbeans 8.01 doesn't recognize gradle for webapp

Tags: netbeans

I create one web app by choosing:  new project --> Java Web -> Web Application--> ....--> Spring Web MVC. Then I also want to use gradle, so I added file of build.gradle in the root of the project. Then I can see the file in "Files" tab, but can't see it in "Projects" tab. I want to see it in "Projects" tab so that I can run build command for gradle. (I added some dependency to it, but netbeans doesn't know it. I could use command line gradle to download the dependency jar, but netbeans still can't use the jar).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but the answer may still be useful to some people.

There is a plugin available for NetBeans to allow Gradle support: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/44510/gradle-support

I can't see a way to show the build.gradle file in the Projects tab of your existing web project, but the Gradle plugin allows you to create Gradle projects, edit the build.gradle file in the Projects window and even launch Gradle tasks from the right-click context menu on the project node.

Gradle projects may not have some of the conveniences of NetBeans web projects, such as the Deploy option in the project node's context menu, but you can always write your own Gradle deploy task.